# Get headlogin name from Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

How can I can the below HeadLoginName as specified below from the master page? (to save it a variable)
Thanks

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <a href="~/login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/logout.aspx"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
  </asp:LoginView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up getting username by using:
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
var view = (LoginView)(Page.Master.FindControl("HeadLoginView");
if (view != null)
{
   var loginName = (LoginName)view.FindControl("HeadLoginName");
   if (loginName != null)
   {

   }
}
```

There are better design patterns to expose these types of things that you could do too, like give the master page an interface definition, and cast the master property to that interface.  Then you can expose whatever you want.

Comment: tried this out but loginName is always empty even when a user is logged in. 
So I used a breakpoint and the value I want is located in the non-public members of this loginName. Any idea how to access this?

Comment: Yes, I see UserName is marked friend/internal.  Non public members can only be accessed by reflection.